# Nested named argument destructuring in ruby block

Tags: ruby

I would like to destructure a nested data structure using only block arguments.

The data (simplified for this example) is like this:

```
response = [
  ["James", { species: "cat", age: "4" }],
  ["Sandy", { species: "dog", age: "7" }],
  ["Horse", { species: "man", age: "34" }]
]
```

I can't find a syntax valid for destructuring this using only block arguments. I imagined it might be this, combining the nested-array destructuring style with named keyword arguments:

```
response.map do |name, (species:, age:)|
  "#{name}: #{species}, #{age}"
end
```

but that gives a syntax error.

Obviously there are plenty of other ways to extract the necessary data e.g. using non-nested keyword arguments:

```
response.map do |name, data|
  proc { |species:, age:|
    "#{name}: #{species}, #{age}"        
  }.(data)
end
```

or

```
response.map do |name, data|
  species, age = data.values_at(:species, :age)
  "#{name}: #{species}, #{age}"        
end
```

or the very obvious

```
response.map do |name, data|
  "#{name}: #{data[:species]}, #{data[:age]}"
end
```

but I'd love to have it in the block arguments, because it appeals to my sense of elegant code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|name, species:, age:|` works (because of the way keyword arguments are handled). It obviously won't work in the general case, but due to the way keyword arguments work, an array whose last element is a hash cleanly corresponds to a parameter list.

Comment: I will leave the general case for others to ponder, thanks for that!

Comment: Note for more recent visitors: sadly, this answer (and the automatic conversion it depends on) stopped working in Ruby 3.0, when keyword arguments became fully separated from positional arguments.